# C-Style unsigned char parsing and manipulation in C/C++ - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, parsing, byte, unsigned-char

Note that I'm using a C++ compiler ( hence, the cast on the `calloc` function calls) to do this, but the code is essentially C.

Basically, I have a `typedef` to an `unsigned char` known as `viByte`, which I'm using to create a string buffer to parse a file from binary (a TGA file, to be exact - but, that's irrelevant).

I'm writing basic functions for it right now; append, prepend, new, etc.

The problem is that, on the first iteration of the first loop in `viByteBuf_Prepend`, I get a segmentation fault. I need to know why, exactly, as this is something which could keep me up all night without some pointers (pun intended).

I also would like to know if my algorithms are correct in terms of how the buffer is *pre-pending* the `viByte` string. For example, I have a feeling that using `memset` too much might be a bad idea, and whether or not my printf format for the unsigned char is correct (I have a feeling it isn't, as nothing is getting output to my console).

Compiling on GCC, Linux.

**Ze Code**

```
#ifdef VI_BYTEBUF_DEBUG
void viByteBuf_TestPrepend( void )
{
    viByteBuf* buf = viByteBuf_New( 4 );

    buf->str = ( viByte* ) 0x1;

    printf(" Before viByteBuf_Prepend => %uc ", buf->str);

    viByteBuf_Prepend( buf, 3, ( viByte* ) 0x2 );

    printf(" After viByteBuf_Prepend => %uc ", buf->str);
}
#endif

viByteBuf* viByteBuf_New( unsigned int len )
{
    viByteBuf* buf = ( viByteBuf* ) calloc( sizeof( viByteBuf ), 1 );

    const int buflen = len + 1;

    buf->str = ( viByte* ) calloc( sizeof( viByte ), buflen );
    buf->len = buflen;

    buf->str[ buflen ] = '\0';

    return buf;
}

void viByteBuf_Prepend( viByteBuf* buf, unsigned int len, viByte* str )
{
    unsigned int pos, i;
    const unsigned int totallen = buf->len + len;
    viByteBuf* tmp = viByteBuf_New( totallen );
    viByte* strpos = buf->str;


    memset( tmp->str, 0, tmp->len );

    int index;

    for( i = 0; i < buf->len; ++i )
    {

       index = ( buf->len - i ) - 1;

       *strpos = buf->str[ 0 ];
       ++strpos;
    }

    memset( buf->str, 0, buf->len );

    printf( "%uc\n", buf->str );

    i = totallen;

    for ( pos = 0; pos < len; ++pos )
    {
        tmp->str[ pos ] = str[ pos ];
        tmp->str[ i ]   = buf->str[ i ];

        --i;
    }

    memset( buf->str, 0, buf->len );

    buf->len = tmp->len;

    memcpy( buf->str, tmp->str, tmp->len );

    viByteBuf_Free( tmp );

    //memset(  )
    //realloc( ( viByteBuf* ) buf, sizeof( viByteBuf ) * tmp->len );
}
```

Many thank yous.

**Update**

Sorry, I should have explicitly posted the code where the segmentation fault lies. It is right here:

```
for( i = 0; i < buf->len; ++i )
{

   index = ( buf->len - i ) - 1;

   *strpos = buf->str[ 0 ]; //<--segmentation fault.
   ++strpos;
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting numbers like 1 and 2 to pointers? Do you think something special is at address 1 and 2?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? It will tell you the exact line you get the segmentation fault, and lets you check variables to see which one might be `NULL`.

Comment: `buf->str[ buflen ] = '\0';` is a buffer overflow. If an array has only 10 entries, then there is no entry number 10 because there is an entry number 0.

Comment: pointing a char * pointer to 0x1 or 0x2 mean you're dead, forget all the rest. you probably meant to set the value of the buffer to 1.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, I have ran it in a debugger. I know the exact line I get the seg fault at, I just don't know *why* I get that seg fault. I've tried many different things to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

On your code you have `buf->str[ buflen ] = '\0';`, but you only allocate space for `buflen`. I think you meant `buf->str[ len ] = '\0';`.